# SPD 2013: email user who submitted an item in an Infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

Created an Infopath form from a SP2013 list.

What's the best stage-by-stage process to set up a workflow (with SharePoint Designer 2013) that

- sends a confirmation email to the user who submits the form, with a copy of the form in the email
- sends a confirmation email to another colleague

Sorry if the answer is already available. Happy to roll back the question if that's already been solved somewhere on the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can also send emails directly from InfoPath itself by setting up new data connection > submit > email message.  There's two options here: 'email the current view' and 'email the form as an attachment'.  You can use the former in this case (attachment would require the user to open in InfoPath).

While this might be the answer you're looking for, I will warn that from my experience, the formatting of these forms in emails can be messy.  If you have a simple form, you might be fine, but if you have a larger form, with lots of formatting, tables, cell spacing, etc., you might find it difficult to get the email to look exactly the way you want.  You can always create a separate email specific view, where you use your rules to swap to that view first, then submit that to email.  Feel free to play with it.

Otherwise, Jason is correct with respect to using emails via workflow.  You'll need to construct them in full.  I agree that it's not actually that bad to setup the emails.  The only way it gets bad is if you end up having to do this a # of different times (and later if you have to go back and edit them).  If for some reason you need to do that, my advice would be try to construct as much of your email message via variables at the start of your workflow that you can then just reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Create a workflow to be run whenever an item is added to the list

Workflow would have 2 steps:

1 to send email to user, you can use fields from the list inside the email content.

2 to send email to another colleague.

Comment: use fields from the list inside the email content.: adding fields one by one sounds time-consuming. no other way possible?

Comment: I don't think so....it really doesn't take that long, you simply select them from a list. Open SPD and have a look.